# How to use Gitlab ci tags

Tags: gitlab-ci

I want to perform the specified operation when the release tags start with v

```yaml
stages:
  - build

build-job:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - "v*"
  image: "node"
  script:
```

But the code doesn't work properly

Answer (score 1):

.gitlab-ci.yml jobs `tags` not Git tag, the `tags` means what GitLab CI Runner do this jobs.

so, if you went running some job when Git release tags start with v, you can use [rules:if](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesif) like:

```yaml
stages:
  - build

build-job:
  stage: build
  image: "node"
  script:
    - some script
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG && $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^v/
```

ref:

- [gitlab-ci.yml tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#tags)

Comment: @Shibin you might also want to [check out the Gitlab-CI Keyword Reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/) if you are new to Gitlab-CI. It's very helpful if you are unfamiliar with Gitlab-CI.